# Given eigen values for a matrix in n dimension how one can generate a corresponding covariance matrix which result in having those eigen values

Tags: matlab, matrix, covariance, correlation, eigenvalue

I am having some difficulties resolving this:
Given eigen values for a matrix in n dimension how one can  generate a corresponding covariance matrix which result in having those eigen values.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any orthogonal matrix R and construct

```
covariance = R*diag(eigenvalues)*R'
```

Comment: R= gallery('orthog',n,k)